# parser.setFeature vs parser.setValidating

Tags: java, xml-parsing, xsd, dtd, xml

What is the diffrence between the following:

```
parser.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/validation",true);
and
parser.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/validation/schema",true);
and
parser.setValidating(true);
```

I found the exact question twice on googling but not the answer

I am using org.apache.commons.digester, i am calling setFeature or setValidating on the digester.

Comment: Your question has no meaningful answer except in the context of a particular parser's API.  If you don't identify the parser, the only reasonable answer is something along the lines of "the three expressions are spelled differently; next question?"  So:  which parser, which API?

Comment: @C. M. Sperberg-McQueen I have incorporated the details in the question.

Answer (score 2):

I was searching for the answer to the same question. You probably already found your answer but for others like me who arrive at this thread.

From what I can see it is implementation specific. SAX doesn't really seem to have a real specification (the spec is their website saxproject.org). At least I didn't find any reference in a spec or javadoc (maybe I overlooked) that isValidating should be in sync with the validation feature.

```
public boolean isValidating()
Indicates if this SAXParserFactory is configured to produce parsers that validate
XML documents as they are parsed.
```

But if you look, for example, at the implementation from Xerces: [org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/xerces/java/trunk/src/org/apache/xerces/jaxp/SAXParserFactoryImpl.java) you will notice that they internally use the validation setting (`isValidation`, `setValidating`) for the validation feature.

- setFeature

  ```
  else if (name.equals(VALIDATION_FEATURE)) {
      setValidating(value);
      return;
  }
  ```
- getFeature

  ```
  else if (name.equals(VALIDATION_FEATURE)) {
      return isValidating();
  }
  ```

Or if you look at the Sun source

```
public void setValidating(boolean validating) {
    putInFeatures(VALIDATION_FEATURE, validating);
}
```

(Example from openjdk-6-src-b31-15_apr_2014)

Another one is the oracle xmlparserv2 from [Oracle XDK](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-technologies/xmldb/xdk-java-082884.html)

Some sample test to prove this (you need the oracle xmlparserv2 jar and you also need a META-INF/services/javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory file with only this `org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl` because the oracle jar is ... well rather dominant)

```
public class SaxParserTest {
    @Test
    public void validationFeatureTestXerces() throws Exception {
        SAXParserFactory parserFactory = org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl.newInstance();

        parserFactory.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/validation", false);
        Assert.assertFalse(parserFactory.isValidating());
        parserFactory.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/validation", true);
        Assert.assertTrue(parserFactory.isValidating());

        parserFactory.setValidating(true);
        Assert.assertTrue(parserFactory.getFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/validation"));
        parserFactory.setValidating(false);
        Assert.assertFalse(parserFactory.getFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/validation"));
    }

    @Test
    public void validationFeatureTestOracle() throws Exception {
        SAXParserFactory parserFactory = oracle.xml.jaxp.JXSAXParserFactory.newInstance();

        parserFactory.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/validation", false);
        Assert.assertFalse(parserFactory.isValidating());
        parserFactory.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/validation", true);
        Assert.assertTrue(parserFactory.isValidating());

        parserFactory.setValidating(true);
        Assert.assertTrue(parserFactory.getFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/validation"));
        parserFactory.setValidating(false);
        Assert.assertFalse(parserFactory.getFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/validation"));
    }

}
```